# Send emails through SMTP using authentication in magento

Tags: php, magento, email, smtp

I am working on a website where after enabling the authentication on SMTP server emails stop working.I installed the SMTP pro extension and on running self test it shows me

```
ASchroder.com SMTP Pro Self-test results
Testing outbound connectivity to Server:
Using SMTP configuration options
Connection to Host SMTP server successful.
Sending test email to your contact form address donotreply@example.com
Unable to send test email. Exception message was: Sender address is not valid for your login. Check your email program settings. ...
Please check and double check your username and password.
Contact Form test email used SMTPPro to send correctly.
Testing failed,
```

But this email address works on contact us form and valid email address.Emails are working on contact us form but not for forget password etc .Guide me so that i can fix the issue.Thanks